# How to link django to my own 404 error page?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Normaly django looks for a url in `url.py` file...
if it finds it load the relevent HTML page and if it doesn't find it shows:
`Page not found (404)` with the msg:

> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
>   settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
>   standard 404 page.

I want to change standard `404 page` that django shows. I have a HTML page that I created `PageNotFound.html` I want django to show everytime there is a `Page not found (404)` when `DEBUG = False`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to show customized HTML when Django returns a 404, you can create an HTML template named 404.html and place it in the top level of your template tree. This template will then be served when DEBUG is set to False.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view

Also, there is an useful section "Customizing error views".

And in the case you want to test your template withour turning DEBUG=False, you can run `manage.py runserver --insecure`.
It will force Django to serving static files with the staticfiles app even if the DEBUG setting is False. But note that it it only for local development and could be insecure. You can read more about this option [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-option---insecure).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote from the Django doc:

> This template should be called 404.html and located in the top level of your template tree.

Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception) for the full text; for non 1.8 doc it should be somewhere around here: **Writing views > Returning errors > The Http404 exception**.

Answer (score 0):

You should create following view:

```
def custom404(request):
    return render(request, '404.html', status=404)
```

And connect it with following construction in `urls.py`:

```
handler404 = 'path.to.views.custom404'
```